# Datagrid add items to datatable from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I got a little problem in my program here. I am trying to add items to my datatable and then get it to show on my datagrid. I can do it with a simple code from my main page but I want an external page to send the results to me but I cant find out what I am doing wrong here.

**MainWindow**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;

namespace Træner_Program
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Display();
    }

     public DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    public DataTable dtBind = new DataTable(); 

    public void Display() 
    { 
        //I create the data in memory 
        //usually the date is get from DataBase and cached in memory to enhance the performance 
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Øvelse");
        dt.Columns.Add("Vægt");
        dt.Columns.Add("Sæt");
        dt.Columns.Add("Gentagelser");
        dt.Columns.Add("Pause");
        dtBind = dt.Copy();
        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Source = dtBind;
        this.dtgPlan.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, bind); 
    } 

    public void AddRow(string Øvelse, string Vægt, string Sæt, string Gentagelser, string Pause)         
    { 
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
        dr["Øvelse"] = Øvelse; 
        dr["Vægt"] = Vægt; 
        dr["Sæt"] = Sæt;
        dr["Gentagelser"] = Gentagelser;
        dr["Pause"] = Pause; 
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dtBind = dt.Copy();
        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Source = dtBind;
        this.dtgPlan.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, bind); 

    } 

    private void btnGem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this is the working command from mainpage
        //AddRow("Bænkpres", "80", "3", "10", "50");
    }

    private void btnTilføj_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tilføjØvelse = new Tilføj_Øvelse();
        tilføjØvelse.Show();



    }
}
}
```

**Add items**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Træner_Program
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Tilføj_Øvelse.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Tilføj_Øvelse : Window
{
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

    public Tilføj_Øvelse()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTilføj_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mw.AddRow("Bænkpres", "80", "3", "10", "50");
        Close();
    }

    private void btnAnuller_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are creating a new MainWindow instead of using the initial one that is calling the Child Window.

A simple fix could be to pass a reference of the Parent MainWindow into the Child like so:

Update the child:

```
public partial class Tilføj_Øvelse : Window
{
    MainWindow mw;

    public Tilføj_Øvelse(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mw = mainWindow;
    }

    private void btnTilføj_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mw.AddRow("Bænkpres", "80", "3", "10", "50");
        Close();
    }

    private void btnAnuller_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

and then update the call to it:

```
  private void btnTilføj_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tilføjØvelse = new Tilføj_Øvelse(this);
        tilføjØvelse.Show();
    }
```

Though, the best (and recommended) way is to use the MVVM pattern and create a shared ViewModel for both of these Windows.

Comment: Tried your fix for my current code and it did not work. Instead im just getting errors for every changes I make of those.
but im looking up on the MVVM pattern you suggested and see what that is but ty for the fast reply

Comment: Okay tried to fix around with the first solution again and here is the error messege given

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Window' to 'Træner_Program.MainWindow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\HansHenrik\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Træner Program\Træner Program\Tilføj Øvelse.xaml.cs 27 18 Træner Program

Comment: @user3415760 try now.. Fixed the param. type

Comment: You're welcome! Though, as recommended, once you get more familiar with WPF you may want to start looking into MVVM. You typically do not want that type of code in the "code-behind"